# Installing Android Studio offline for multiple computers

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been trying to configure Android Studio 3.4.2 offline by downloading the installer and the SDK and such. There's a tutorial on the site that says Offline dependencies, but upon doing what the site says, Android studio still cannot sync with Gradle properly.

I have a laptop that I synced online and is now working even on offline mode. I was wondering if I can use the downloaded files from my laptop and pass it on different computers. Would that be possible though?

Answer (score 0):

Download Android Studio offline with full SDK - No Need to wait hours for android studio plugins
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3k_sScH8_6U&list=PL6Q9UqV2Sf1hVgtxFVZ7f0_Ir6FF6ZEDe&index=1

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I already have the SDK and I already installed Android Studio.. What I'm asking is about the dependencies that the IDE needed. Will that download link you've included in the video includes all necessary files to create an app offline without syncing with Gradle?